# Conflict between two linux shared objects defining the same function name

Tags: linux, pyqt, ld, python-embedding, python-extensions

My problem deals with Python, Qt, PyQt and other stuff, but the question is actually about how Linux's `ld.so` actually works.

**THE QUESTION**

If a program loads two different shared libraries which both have the same entry point name (i.e. they both define a function with the same name and signature) how can it tell which version is it calling?

**MY PROBLEM**

I have a third party, proprietary Linux application that was written in C++ (though the original language is irrelevant) and it's linked dynamically to Qt3.3. The application embeds a python interpreter which can be used to write scripts for it.

You can even use the application's embedded python instead of the original one using a command such as:

```
/path/to/the/program/python
```

And it shows the following:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Sep 16 2011, 18:16:32) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Using gcc 4.1.2 I have built and installed PyQt4 from sources, against the Qt4 libraries that the system also has. I believe the build was successful because I can run a small PyQt4 application using:

```
/path/to/the/program/python mypyqtapp.py
```

However, if I load the program with its GUI and load the same script, it crashes at the first `PyQt4` call, which is an instantiation of the `QApplication` class.

Since the python environment is the same, I suspect it might be some kind of shared library conflict between Qt3 and Qt4. However, the command `strace -e trace=file` reveals that python is locating and loading the right Qt4 libraries in both cases.

So, my question is if a program loads two shared different libraries that define the same function, how does it know it's calling the right one? Does the linux loader `ld.so` somehow qualify the entry points with a file name or something? I suspect that my problem might lie there, that the app has eventually loaded two different instances of `QApplication` and it's calling the wrong one, but how `ld.so` actually works internally escapes me.

It might also be that my problem is caused by something completely different.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try a debugger like gdb/ddd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conflict symbol only detected on linkage(ld) stage, loader(ld-linux.so) don't check conflict symbol.

When multiple library providing duplicated symbol, the one first loaded is used.

Actually somebody can make use of this feature. By providing LD_PRELOAD=overwrite.so, overwrite.so can overwrite any function the program needed.

Comment: The real worl problem that motivated this question is long obsolete and gone now. I guess if I were to try the LD_PRELOAD solution that the application would crash just the same only at a different point. I am accepting this answer because it does provide a straight answer to the specific question formulated as to how ld.so is working. Thank you.